# Box ApI Upload Folder Not working

Tags: upload, box-api, box

I am trying to upload folder using sample project Helloworld api of BOX. But it gives Error.

What to pass as FOLDER NAME here "0" . please give me Solution.

```
BoxAndroidClient client = b.getClient();
        Intent intent = 
FolderPickerActivity.getLaunchIntent(getApplicationContext(),"0", 
(BoxAndroidOAuthData) client.getAuthData(), Box_connect.CLIENT_ID,
Box_connect.CLIENT_SECRET);
startActivityForResult(intent, UPLOAD_REQUEST);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I found from their documentation, their using 1 for default folder. So try 1 instead of 0.

```
BoxAndroidClient client = b.getClient();
    Intent intent = 
FolderPickerActivity.getLaunchIntent(getApplicationContext(),"1", 
(BoxAndroidOAuthData) client.getAuthData(), Box_connect.CLIENT_ID,
Box_connect.CLIENT_SECRET);
startActivityForResult(intent, UPLOAD_REQUEST);
```